# Trying to create a database element via trigger

Tags: sql, oracle

Good morning,

I am developing an application with oracle apex and I have found the following issue:

- I have created a form in order to insert a class called EXPEDIENTE in my database.
- Whenever an EXPEDIENTE is created, a parent class for it must also be created automatically (EXPEDIENTE_GENERAL), and its ID (EXPEDIENTE_GENERAL_ID) must be set in EXPEDIENTE as its FK
- I am trying to do this via Trigger in my database, but I keep receiving the error "FK missing" whenever I try to insert an EXPEDIENTE

The trigger should behave as follows :

**Before insert EXPEDIENTE -> Create EXPEDIENTE_GENERAL -> Give EXPEDIENTE_GENERAL an ID -> Use that ID as FK in EXPEDIENTE** .

This is what my trigger looks like now, but it's not working:

```
    create or replace TRIGGER TV_EXPEDIENTES_TRI
BEFORE INSERT ON TV_EXPEDIENTES

FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  id_exp_gen  NUMBER;
BEGIN
SELECT TV_EXPEDIENTES_GENERALES_SEQ.nextval
  INTO id_exp_gen
  FROM dual;
  INSERT INTO TV_EXPEDIENTES_GENERALES VALUES (id_exp_gen,'CAN');
  SELECT TV_EXPEDIENTES_SEQ.nextval
  INTO :new.C_ID_EXPEDIENTE
  FROM dual;

  :new.C_ID_EXPEDIENTE_GENERAL:=id_exp_gen;

END;
```

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Can you please add the code of the trigger? How can we find the error without having a look at the code? Also show us how you created the FK constraint

Comment: I added the code, thank you for your help

Comment: Why are you selecting the nextval twice? If I understand your question, tv_expedientes.c_id_expediente should be equal to some tv_expedientes_generales.c_id_expediente_general? if so, remove the second select from your code, and remove '_general' from your les statement in the trigger.

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried it, with such tables:

```
create table expediente_general
  (id   number primary key);

create table expediente 
  (id         number primary key,
   id_general number constraint fk_exgen references expediente_general (id)
  );
```

Trigger:

```
create or replace trigger trg_bi_exp
  before insert on expediente
  for each row
begin
  insert into expediente_general (id) values (:new.id_general);
end;
/
```

In Apex:

- I created a form on a table (source is `EXPEDIENTE`),
- set `ID` column to be a `text column` (it is hidden by default),
- ran the page,
- entered both `ID` and `ID_GENERAL`
- pushed the `CREATE` button

The result:

```
SQL> select * from expediente;

        ID ID_GENERAL
---------- ----------
         1        100

SQL> select * from expediente_general;

        ID
----------
       100

SQL>
```

So ... it *works*.

Comment: thank you for your reply, but i want Expediente general , id and id_general to be created automatically via trigger when i try to create an Expediente, so I only have to set the remaining fields of the Expediente

Comment: If code I posted doesn't do what you want (although, I don't understand *why* as - to me - it looks to be OK), please, edit your question and copy/paste your own code so that we could see what you did and why it doesn't work.

Comment: hello again, what you posted is what I need, but I need both Ids to be created automatically when you insert the Expediente, the code is already pasted. I am sorry if I am being dumb but my brain is completely stucked here. Thank you so much again